# Issues while installing Ionic (Cordova)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I run the command to install ionic I get the following messages. Post that if I run "ionic" I get this error:

D:\application>ionic
'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
D:\application>npm install -g ionic
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browseri
fy requires through2@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\through2,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.3
ionic@1.3.11 C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic
+-- proxy-middleware@0.7.0
+-- connect-livereload@0.5.2
+-- progress@1.1.7
+-- open@0.0.5
+-- colors@0.6.2
+-- ncp@0.4.2
+-- underscore@1.7.0
+-- crc@3.2.1
+-- q@1.0.1
+-- semver@4.3.0
+-- shelljs@0.2.6
+-- cross-spawn@0.2.3 (lru-cache@2.5.0)
+-- event-stream@3.0.20 (duplexer@0.1.1, stream-combiner@0.0.4, from@0.1.3, map-
stream@0.0.5, pause-stream@0.0.11, split@0.2.10, through@2.3.6)
+-- optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
+-- npm@2.1.3
+-- finalhandler@0.2.0 (escape-html@1.0.1, debug@2.0.0)
+-- connect@3.1.1 (parseurl@1.3.0, utils-merge@1.0.0, debug@1.0.4, finalhandler@
0.1.0)
+-- form-data@0.1.4 (mime@1.2.11, async@0.9.0, combined-stream@0.0.7)
+-- serve-static@1.7.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, escape-html@1.0.1, parseurl@1.3.0, se
nd@0.10.1)
+-- opbeat-ionic@1.1.3 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, console-log-level@1.0.0, stac
kman@0.2.2, after-all@2.0.1)
+-- xml2js@0.4.4 (sax@0.6.1, xmlbuilder@2.5.2)
+-- unzip@0.1.9 (setimmediate@1.0.2, pullstream@0.4.1, readable-stream@1.0.33, m
atch-stream@0.0.2, fstream@0.1.31, binary@0.3.0)
+-- tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, qs@0.5.6, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0
.3)
+-- prompt@0.2.12 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, winston@0.6.2,
utile@0.2.1)
+-- request@2.51.0 (caseless@0.8.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0,
forever-agent@0.5.2, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, oauth-sign@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, m
ime-types@1.0.2, node-uuid@1.4.2, qs@2.3.3, combined-stream@0.0.7, tough-cookie@
0.12.1, http-signature@0.10.1, hawk@1.1.1, bl@0.9.4, form-data@0.2.0)
+-- vinyl-fs@0.3.7 (graceful-fs@3.0.5, lodash@2.4.1, strip-bom@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.
6, mkdirp@0.5.0, through2@0.6.3, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
+-- archiver@0.5.1 (lodash@2.4.1, readable-stream@1.1.13, lazystream@0.1.0, zip-
stream@0.1.4, file-utils@0.1.5)
+-- gulp@3.8.8 (interpret@0.3.10, pretty-hrtime@0.2.2, archy@0.0.2, deprecated@0
.0.1, minimist@1.1.0, semver@3.0.1, tildify@1.0.0, chalk@0.5.1, orchestrator@0.3
.7, gulp-util@3.0.3, liftoff@0.12.1)

D:\application>ionic start myApp tabs
'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\application>
```

Comment: Did you try to close and start up your console again? Restart your pc? Does the node_modules global bin exist in your PATH?

Comment: Yes, I have closed and started console again; and also restarted my system. I have got these 2 bin in my path JAVA_HOME & ANT_HOME. Can't see any other.. Let me know if am missing something. Thanks

Comment: @Ricconnect Issue resovled... Thanks for your time... :)